# when I vagrant up, I get error

Tags: hyperledger

I have just successfully built the hyperledger environment. And I want to `vagrant up` to open my virtualbox. But I got error as following:

> ==> default: ++ export DOCKER_STORAGE_BACKEND=
>
> ==> default: ++ DOCKER_STORAGE_BACKEND=
>
> ==> default: ++ cd /hyperledger/devenv
>
> ==> default: ++ ./setup.sh

Anyone knows what happens? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not an error. It might take some time.
If you're behind a proxy check the notes in http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv/

Comment: Thank you for your help. And I typed `sudo modprobe vboxnetflt`, it works.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I had to configure the proxy up to 3 times when setting it up on a new computer.